# Get nested div using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

Given the following HTML file,

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
        function initialize() {
           document.getElementById('id2')
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1">
       <div id="id2"></div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to access the inner div tag using the

```
document.getElementById
```

function in the html header, which, although I read the contrary, does not seem to work (in Safari 6.0.5.), while it works to access the outer tag.

Comment: Please show where you place the JavaScript in your HTML file and post your exact JavaScript code.

Comment: @Felix Kling The script is placed in the html header

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNKDu/) that shows that it works. The script needs to be called after the element is created.

```
<body>
    <div id="id1">
        <div id="id2"></div>
    </div>
    <script>alert(document.getElementById('id2'));</script>
</body>
```

Or:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function getElement (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        };
    </script>
    <div id="id1">
        <div id="id2"></div>
    </div>
    <script>alert(getElement('id2'));</script>

</body>
```